# taking barcode output on a jsp or html page

Tags: java, jsp, barcode

I have barcode scanner which scans the barcode printed on backside of a file which is connected through a usb port if a text file is open on desktop then on scanning the barcode it automatically displays output in the text file.I am using java netbeans and **I want to take this output as an entry in the textinput box in a jsp or an html page which on submitting stores it in database** so i know how to connect to database and the insert code I want to know how to take the barcode output as an entry in the textinput box.

Comment: You probably want a servlet to "send" the barcode to you jsp, and handle the "post" later

Comment: could you give an example code for reference please

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html